# I need to do sum of the columns separately using jquery and show individual column sum below each column in a new row

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my html... This is being generated by a tool which we use for programming. table class is mrquestiontable. Inside table each input box has class mredit. Using mredit i am able to do sum of all the boxes but not sum of columns separately. Please help here..

```
<table summary="Please indicate the type of hospital/ clinic where you are 
currently practicing and the proportion of time spent in each practice." 
class="mrQuestionTable">
<tr><td></td>
<td><span><center><b>Main Practice</b></center></span></td>
<td><span><center><b>Secondary Practice</b></center></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><span class="mrQuestionText">Public Hospital</span></td>
<td><span><input type="text" class="mrEdit" value=""/></span></td>
<td><span><input type="text" class="mrEdit" value=""/></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><span class="mrQuestionText">Private Hospital</span></td>
<td><span><input type="text" class="mrEdit" value=""/></span></td>
<td><span><input type="text" class="mrEdit" value=""/></span></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: please share the jquery code you have used

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the column you will first need a class adding to the column/row you want.

`<td class="calculate_R"><span><input type="text" class="mrEdit" value=""/></span></td>`

As for the jquery it could be something like this,

```
var total = 0;
// iterate through each td based on class
$(".calculate_R").each(function() {

    var value = $(this).text();
    //only if the value is a number
    if(!isNaN(value) && value.length != 0) {
        total += parseFloat(value);
    }
});
```

Then just wrap it in all in a function.

```
 function calculate_total() {
   //above code
 }
```

Call it with `$(calculate_total);`

Answer (score 0):

I've written a little something that may suit your needs. It will automatically add an extra row to display the added values underneath your table. When you edit something in an input it will calculate the column total and put it into the label underneath the table.

```js
function setup() {
  $('.mrQuestionTable').append('<tr><td></td><td><label></label></td><td><label></label></td><tr>');
}

setup();

$('input').blur(function(e) {
  var index = $(this).parent().parent().index();
  var elements = $('.mrQuestionTable td:nth-child(' + (index + 1) + ')'); //Skipping the first column
  var label = elements.find('label');
  var inputs = elements.find('input');
  var count = 0;
  label.text('');
  inputs.each(function(e) {
    value = parseInt($(this).val());
    if (value) {
      count += value;
    }
    label.text(count);
  });
});
```

```html
<table summary="Please indicate the type of hospital/ clinic where you are 
currently practicing and the proportion of time spent in each practice." class="mrQuestionTable">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><span><center><b>Main Practice</b></center></span></td>
    <td><span><center><b>Secondary Practice</b></center></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span class="mrQuestionText">Public Hospital</span></td>
    <td><span><input type="text" class="mrEdit" value=""/></span></td>
    <td><span><input type="text" class="mrEdit" value=""/></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span class="mrQuestionText">Private Hospital</span></td>
    <td><span><input type="text" class="mrEdit" value=""/></span></td>
    <td><span><input type="text" class="mrEdit" value=""/></span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```